# Retrieving information from the array that mounted the map (MapKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

I have an array with several dictionaries. In every dictionary I have some information. I want to add a point on the map for each item inside the array. I do not have anything but didSelectForAnnotation method, how do I get inside the array as certain information of that object? In a table I would use the indexPath but an annotation does not have that indexPath. Is there a solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set custom information with you `MKPointAnnotation` then you need to subclass it and create a custom property that you can use latter to differentiate it from other array object.

```
class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

     var arrayIndex: Int!
}
```

Now you need to create annotation with `MyAnnotation` class, and set the arrayIndex with your array index where you are creating annotation.

```
for (index,item) in yourArray.enumerated() {
    let annotation = MyAnnotation()

    //Set arrayIndex for your annotation
    annotation.arrayIndex = 1    

    //Set coordinate and title from your array
    annotation.coordinate = locations
    annotation.title = "Zaid Homes"
    annotation.subtitle = "Hay aljameaa"
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Now in `didSelect view` method of mapView you can get that index.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation {
        print(annotation.arrayIndex)
        print(yourArray[annotation.arrayIndex])
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and later I will answer.

Comment: I receive this error: "Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_MKUserLocation' (0x7c985000) to 'Floop.MyAnnotation'"