# MKMapViewDelegate + JSON ALAMOFIRE

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, mkmapview, ios10

app download latitude and longitude from server on the 'moreViewController' I have label and when I tap pin how can I transform correct latitude or longitude (and image to another view) to this label?

```
{
  "latitude": 40.9233,
  "longitude": 20.000,
  "image" : "xxxx.xxx/xxx.jpg"
}
{
  "latitude": 50.9233,
  "longitude": 19.320,
  "image" : "xxxx.xxx/yyy.jgp"
}
```

So I download it and save to global `var test = [String:AnyObject]()`

```
Alamofire.request("website").responseJSON { response in

     print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
     let json = response.result.val
     print("JSON: \(json)" 
     let jsonTab = json as? Array<Any>
         for item in jsonTab as! [AnyObject] {
          self.test["lat"] = item["lat"] as? Double! as AnyObject?
          self.test["lng"] = item["lng"] as? Double! as AnyObject?
          self.addPin(lat: self.test["lat"] as! Double, lng: self.test["lng"] as! Double)
```

and add pin

```
func addPin(lat:Double, lng:Double) {
        let testPin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        dropPin.coordinate = testPin
        dropPin.title = "test"
        mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
    }
```

now add right button and segue to next view

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "more", sender: self)
    }

    var annotationIdentifier = ""
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        if view == nil {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            view?.canShowCallout = true
            view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        } else {
            view?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return view
    }

    var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation!
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.destination is moreViewController {
            print("123")
            let destViewController:moreViewController = segue.destination as! moreViewController
            destViewController.lat = "\(latTest)"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `performSegue` with sender instead of passing current controller reference pass the selected view's annotation.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "more", sender: view.annotation)
}
```

Now in `prepareForSegue` method access this sender property and get the annotation from it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.destination is moreViewController {

        let destViewController:moreViewController = segue.destination as! moreViewController
        if let annotation = sender as? MKAnnotation {
            destViewController.lat = "\(annotation.coordinate.latitude)"
            destViewController.long = "\(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"
        }

    }
}
```

**Note:** You have set `lat` and `long` value in test dictionary, so it will over write the value and it will contains only last array object's `lat` and `long` value.

Comment: @k0le Welcome mate :)

Comment: sorry but I have another question I don't see but this "place" have own name as String and id as String on json how can I transport it with lat and long correct?

Comment: @k0le Don't get you can you edit your post with more details.

Comment: @k0le For that you need to make CustomAnnotation by implementing `MKPointAnnotation`.Check this similar answer of my   http://stackoverflow.com/a/42135847/6433023 here i have created Int property with customAnnotation class instead of that you need to make Dictionary property and set the whole JSON dictionary object with Annotation later you need to cast it to customAnnotation and then simply use information that you want.